# Undefined control sequence error occurred. Which package should I use here ? or any other mistakes?

Tags: tables, errors, amsmath, undefined, amssymb

```
\multirow{2}[2]{*}{1.1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{Q>10\newline{}Good to very good}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{I}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{50}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{25mm $\straightphi$ spot rockbolts 2.5m long as required}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[2]{*}{-}} & \multirow{2}[2]{*}{} \bigstrut[t]\\
      &       &       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &       &       &  \bigstrut[b]\\
\hline
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of code snippets. This makes our lives easier and increases the chance of people helping you.

Comment: `\mulritow` needs the `multirow` package, `\multicolumn` is build into the kernel.

Comment: none of  `\multirow` , `\straightphi`  and  `\bigstrut` are defined commands in the latex format